# I want to install PHP and mySQL - which basic tutorials are recommended?

Tags: apache2, mysql, live-usb, php

I intent to install PHP and mySQL on live Ubuntu USB stick with persisten storage. Is it possible? If yes, any recommendations for basic tutorials or manuals?

Is [**this**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) the right way to **install and configurate Apache** server?

Comment: Tutorials for using apt to install those packages? Or are you looking for something more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're installing is called a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) stack.  This looks like a good one: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Whenever you need info you can use the `lamp` keyword in Google, that link I just posted is one of the first results when you Google `how to install LAMP`.

Comment: Is it possible to install PHP, test it that it works and only after that to add mySQL support?

Comment: Yes you can, just only follow the Apache and PHP installation instructions in that/any tutorial.  Once you see that those work, you can install MySQL.  You don't have to do it all at once.

Comment: "Works" if you try in a CLI interface. Web pages won't render php code before apache is installed.

Comment: Can I install a LAMP on USB pendrive with Live Ubuntu Persistent Storage on it?

Comment: @BlueSkies Yes, those packages are small enough to fit on 4GB of disk space and still allow plenty of room for content and other non-related file storage.